# sql statement with 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have a master table called `tblposts`

```
post_id Post_subeject    comments_limit
1        summer holidays  1
2        hotels in ny     1
3        london vs paris  5
```

and a detailed table called `tblcomments`

```
comment_id Post_id Comment  date
1          1       CommentA 10/1/2014
2          2       CommentB 2/2/2014
3          2       CommentC 12/12/2013
4          2       CommentD 3/6/2014
5          3       CommentE 2/8/2013
6          2       CommentF 9/2/2014
```

I want to run an SQL statment that will display that posts, that the number of their comments after 1/1/2014, is more than the `comments_limit`

Please advice!

To be aquarate I want to run an SQL statment that will display all posts with one additional column named total__post_commends_afterdate and one additional column with post comment_limit

I want all posts to be displayed which means also that with no comments at all or no comments after that date

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and the issues that you have with it?

Comment: sorry I didnt give more info. My solution was like Ganesh_devlekar, but to be aquarate I want to run an SQL statment that will display all posts with one additional column named total__post_commends_afterdate and one additional column with post comment_limit

I want all posts to be displayed which means also that with no comments at all or no comments after that date (total__post_commends_afterdate will be 0 in this case)

Comment: Update your question with the clarifying information. Reading it in comments is not so nice and clear

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select po.post_id  from tblPosts po
LEFT join tblcomments com
on po.post_id=com.comment_id
where com.date>'20140101'
HAVING COUNT(com.comment_id)>po.comments_limit
GROUP BY po.post_id
```

Comment: thank you for you reply. To be aquarate I want to run an SQL statment that will display all posts with one additional column named total__post_commends_afterdate and one additional column with post comment_limit

I want all posts to be displayed which means also that with no comments at all or no comments after that date